# Devexpress Mask for a TextEdit

Tags: devexpress

I'm using Devexpress

I have a TextEdit when i want that users to have 2 dates as following :

dd/MM/yyyy - dd/MM/yyyy  ( for example : 02/12/2011-03/09/2013 )

I've tried to set the mask as above but is not working.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to set mask:

```
textEdit.Properties.Mask.MaskType = MaskType.Simple;
textEdit.Properties.Mask.EditMask = "00/00/0000-00/00/0000";
```

However, TextEdit can have only one EditValue property, so it won't allow you to store two DateTime values.

You can add custom validating with Validating event:

```
private void TextEdit_Validating(object sender, CancelEventArgs e)
{
    string textValue = (string)(sender as TextEdit).EditValue;
    var dates = textValue?.Split('-').Select(x => { DateTime.TryParse(x, out DateTime result); return result; });
    if (dates == null || dates.Any(x => x == null))
    {
        e.Cancel = true;
    }
}
```

But it seems messy, so i recommend you to use two DateEdit controls instead.

Comment: Note that the DateEdit also allows for a date range selection so you don't necessarily need to use 2.

Comment: @brendon I set the dateEdit selection mode to Multiple , but on runtime i don;t know how to select 2 dates

Comment: If you want to do it programmatically at runtime, set the DateEdit's [SelectedRanges](https://documentation.devexpress.com/WindowsForms/DevExpress.XtraEditors.DateEdit.SelectedRanges.property) property

Comment: @brendon No , i want that users to be able to select a range of dates and this range should be saved later on database.

Comment: The user just needs to click on a date and then drag the cursor to the ending date. If a single date is already selected, clicking another while pressing the SHIFT key will also select that range. It sounds like using 2 DateEdit controls might be easier for you though, as suggested by @Maxim above.